# List all commits of a branch since it was created from master with JGit

Tags: java, jgit, git-log

I'm trying to use JGit to get a commit log specific to a branch since it was created.  I've found several posts in forums that sound like they are describing this, but they seem to all return commits to the branch and everything prior.

I basically want to emulate this git command with JGit

```
git log master..testBranch
```

which does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following snippet should do this, it walks the branch `testBranch` backwards until the commits are on `master`.

I have also added this to the sample snippet in my [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowLog.java)

```
        try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
            Iterable<RevCommit> logs = git.log()
                    .not(repository.resolve("master"))
                    .add(repository.resolve("remotes/origin/testBranch"))
                    .call();
            count = 0;
            for (RevCommit rev : logs) {
                System.out.println("Commit: " + rev /* + ", name: " + rev.getName() + ", id: " + rev.getId().getName() */);
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("Had " + count + " commits only on test-branch");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for adding it.  I had already looked for this in your cookbook which has been helpful.

I had found much more complex example that worked, but I knew it had to much simpler.